# How to change a single property of a style component already created using conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles

I got the following code:

```
function App() {
...
const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);

const styles = {
  backgroundColor:'lightGray',
  ...
}

  return (
         <div>
           <h1> style:{notification ? styles:{styles.backgroundColor:'red'}}>Test</h1>
         </div>
   ) 
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is just changing the backgroundColor property of the already created style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function App() {
...
const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);

const styles = {
  backgroundColor:'lightGray',
  ...
}

  return (
         <div>
           <h1> style={notification ? {...styles, backgroundColor: 'red'} : styles}>Test</h1>
         </div>
   ) 
}
```

Comment: dang...destructuring... I knew I was missing something. Thx!